# How to find out if a socket is closed

Tags: c, winapi, sockets

I have a simple client server program that I made but the main issue is that once a connection is established between the client and server, if the client closes the program, the server repeatedly executes the last message and that creates huge problems sometimes. So what I want to is if there is any function that I can call to get the state of a SOCKET structure so if the client closes the program, the server will know to stop. I just need the function what to look for from the function for a bad socket. By the way I am writing this program in Win32 c. I tried if(mySocket==SOCKET_ERROR) which didn't seem to work... unless I used it wrong. I'm just beginning networking.

```
if(!sockServer.RecvData( recMessage, STRLEN )){return 0;}
// where
bool Socket::RecvData( char *buffer, int size )
{
    int i = recv( mySocket, buffer, size, 0 );
    if(!i){return false;}
    buffer[i] = '\0';
    return true;
}  //this isn't working
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the peer closes the socket, `read()` and `recv()` will return zero. You must be ignoring that if 'the server repeatedly executes the last message', which of course would 'create huge problems' not just 'sometimes' but *always*.

**EDIT 1:** You're also making another elementary TCP programming error: you are assuming that you receive an entire message in a single read. There are no messages in TCP, it's just a byte stream, and no 1::1 correspondence between writes and reads (`send()` and `recv()`). `recv()` can return zero or as few as 1 bytes. You have to organize your own message boundaries, and you have to loop until you receive an entire message you can deal with.

**EDIT 2:** You are also ignoring all errors in your receive method. You must look for `recv()` returning `-1`, and not proceed with the logic that processes the data you were trying to read. At a minimum you should call `perror()` or check `errno` or in Winsock `WSAGetLastError()`.

When you get either an error or an EOS you must stop looping, close the socket, forget about the connection, and forget about this client.

Comment: hmm that didn't seem to work. I have implemented what i think you told me do above in my edit

Comment: @Iowa15 You have to do more than that. You have to observe that your methods returned `false` and `zero` respectively; exit whatever loop is driving this logic; close the socket; and do whatever other housekeeping is required to forget about this socket, this client, this connection.

Answer (score 0):

How about listening for FD_CLOSE in your Main message proc?  you are using WSAAsyncSelect with FD_CLOSE right?

Comment: He wants to detect whether the client side ended the connection. The server side socket might still be valid then. No `FD_CLOSE` would not be issues, as the server side socket would not be `close()`d automagically, when the client ends.