# Server incorrectly detects closing of socket

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp

I have a server based on BSD sockets, with `select` to detect events. It keeps closing connections when clients still have data to send (the clients throw Connection reset by peer).

This is my code on server side:

```
if (FD_ISSET(sd,&readfds)){//we have an event from select               
   int count=0;
   ioctl(sd,FIONREAD,&count);//should return available data 
   if(count==0){    
    u_int8_t c;
    count=recv(sd, &c, 1, MSG_PEEK);//this should just check if data available without reading
    if(count==0)close(sd);
        }
   else if(count>expected_message_size)//do something
   else //do nothing until enough data arrives
   }
```

[Google says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12924948/how-to-find-out-if-a-socket-is-closed) that if recv returns 0, it means client closed socket, but it does not seem to work. As far as I know, it *should not* work, because recv/read returns the amount of data read, but we are dealing with internet communication here - what if there is no data *right now*, because we've read everything the client has sent *so far*, but there is more to come?

[man recv](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recv.2.html) actually says:

> Datagram sockets in various domains (e.g., the UNIX and Internet
> domains) permit zero-length datagrams.  When such a datagram is
> received, the return value is 0.

[More searching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17705239/is-there-a-way-to-detect-that-tcp-socket-has-been-closed-by-the-remote-peer-wit) led me to the MSG_PEEK method, but that did not help. What am I doing wrong?

I am on Linux, and do not need to support any other OS.

Comment: the code is strange ... why call recv if you know count is zero ? it doesn't make sense ... also, if FD_ISSET is true you could just call recv and accumulate whatever the client has sent, no need to mess around with ioctl

Answer (score 1):

If no data are available `recv` either blocks (blocking socket) or returns -1 to signal an error. If the error is EAGAIN (also known as EWOULDBLOCK) this means that currently no data are available.

If `recv` returns 0 on a **TCP socket** it means that the peer has closed the socket. With **datagram sockets (UDP)** this is different since there is no concept of a connection and thus not of a connection establishment and closing either. Here a return 0 might actually indicate that a datagram with size 0 was received.

Comment: I am using TCP sockets, so this just confirms what I read elsewhere - that return value of 0 should mean peer has closed the socket. Yet, it just does not work.

Comment: @DamirGruncl: *" it just does not work"* - please provide a more complete example to demonstrate your problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and make sure to provide everything so that your problem is actually reproducible by others.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using TCP sockets, you should just be able to `recv` and if that returns 0, then you close the connection. using both `ioctl` and `recv` with `MSG_PEEK` seems unnecessary. You can do something like this:

```c
int count = recv(sd, buf, MAX_SIZE, 0);

if (count == 0)
{
    // the client has closed the connection
    close(sd);
}
else if (count == -1)
{
    // there was an error receiving data from the client
}
else 
{
    // do stuff with buf
}
```

if you have set `O_NONBLOCK` on `sd` and you want to check if `recv` would have blocked, you can `#include <errno.h>` and check for `EWOULDBLOCK` and `EAGAIN`:

```c
...
if (count == -1)
{
    if ((errno == EWOULDBLOCK) || (errno == EAGAIN))
    {
         // recv would have blocked
    }
    else 
    {
         // a different error occurred 
    }
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out - I had a listen function on a socket to accept incoming connections, and the backlog parameter was 3. Increasing it to 100 fixed the problem. I have no idea why that produced Connection reset by peer rather than Connection refused, but that's what happened.

Comment: Well, if it is a linux box and the sysctl tcp_abort_on_overflow is true and the accept queue is full (3 connections waiting to be accepted) then it will reply with a reset.